# how to add password to an account that was created using --disabled-password?

Tags: ubuntu, users, amazon-ec2

I am following the guide [add new user accounts with SSH access to my Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/) the point 2 has this note

> If you add the new_user to an Ubuntu instance, include the
> --disabled-password option to avoid adding a password to the new account

Because I use an instance of ubuntu, I proceed as the note suggests

```
$ sudo adduser new_user --disabled-password
```

But when I get to the optional section in step 7 I want to allow the new user to use sudo so I try the following, as the guide tells me

```
$ sudo passwd new_user
```

But here a password is required, I try to just press enter but keep asking for a password that it obviously doesn't have. I suppose there is something that skipped the guide, could you tell me how to proceed in this case

Answer (score 2):

When you run the command:

```
$ sudo passwd new_user
```

`sudo` will prompt you for *your* password (to verify that you are you), then it will run `passwd` (as root), which will prompt you for the new password for `new_user`.